# Take the world from another point of view

Tags: riddle

<sub>In a BBC Interview, The Pleasure of Finding Things Out, great scientist Richard Feynman says:</sub>

> <sub>When he (Carl Feynman) was very small we used to rock him to bed, you know, and tell him stories, and I'd make up a story about little people that were about so high [who] would walk along and they would go on picnics and so on and they lived in the ventilator; and they'd go through these woods which had great big long tall blue things like trees, but without leaves and only one stalk, and they had to walk between them and so on; and he'd gradually catch on [that] that was the rug, the nap of the rug, the blue rug, and he loved this game because I would describe all these things from an odd point of view and he liked to hear the stories and we got all kinds of wonderful things—he even went to a moist cave where the wind kept going in and out—it was coming in cool and went out warm and so on. It was inside the dog's nose that they went</sub>

---

Take the world from the point of view of an pencilhead sized man. Find out, where he actually went, in these cases:

> (...) After sliding down on the smooth slide, I landed on something which looked like the exterior of a planetarium sized sphere. Brownish. A bit rubbery, 'cause when I hit the surface, it was bit soft. Numerous whitish tentacles was there, long like ropes, and thick like that, so I took a hold of them, and climbed. Above, what looked like some pyramid, from which very loud noise was coming. Before the pyramid, there was some half open moon like pinkish holes, and I could see gigantic whitish plates inside that hole. Between the pyramid and the hole, there was also another forest of straight (and a bit hard this time) whitish rope-like-structure.

(...)

> I...I could see a very large - like dozen football fields clumped up - blackish, very smooth area in front. Not very smooth - there were some occasional slabs of smooth square-ish plates rising from the surface. (...) And out of nowhere, ten gigantic cylindrical rods came , and started pushing the plates. The sound was like when you do clip-clop sound, but many times louder

(...)

> I can see a big transparent tube in front of me. Very big - it's radius is roughly three quarter's of me, but it is very long - like a football field. Inside the rod, I can see a smaller cylinder - but it's not transparent, it's blue. At one end, it was bit conical, and an tiny shiny cylinder came from the tip of the cone.

Answer (score 5):

**The first one is:** (improved thanks to @Rubio's comment)

> a face (probably from an old brown-colored person)

sliding down the smooth slide

> probably the wood of a bed where the person is lying

I landed on something which looked like the exterior of a planetarium sized sphere. Brownish. A bit rubbery, 'cause when I hit the surface, it was bit soft. Numerous whitish tentacles was there, long like ropes, and thick like that, so I took a hold of them, and climbed

> the head of the person and the tenticles are a beard

Above, what looked like some pyramid, from which very loud noise was coming.

> the nose

Before the pyramid, there was some half open moon like pinkish holes, and I could see gigantic whitish plates inside that hole.

> the mouth and teath

Between the pyramid and the hole, there was also another forest of straight (and a bit hard this time) whitish rope-like-structure.

> moustache

**The second one is:**

> a piano

I...I could see a very large - like dozen football fields clumped up - blackish, very smooth area in front.

> the outside of the piano is often very smooth and polished

Not very smooth - there were some occasional slabs of smooth square-ish plates rising from the surface. (...)

> the piano keys

(...) And out of nowhere, ten gigantic cylindrical rods came , and started pushing the plates. The sound was like when you do clip-clop sound, but many times louder

> fingers pushing the piano keys, making music

**The third one is:**

> a pen

I can see a big transparent tube in front of me. Very big - it's radius is roughly three quarter's of me, but it is very long - like a football field.

> the pen itself, of transparent plastic

Inside the rod, I can see a smaller cylinder - but it's not transparent, it's blue.

> the ink holder inside the pen

At one end, it was bit conical, and an tiny shiny cylinder came from the tip of the cone.

> the tip of the pen where you can write with.

Comment: I think the second one is more likely a mechanical keyboard than a piano, I wouldn't really describe piano sounds as clip-clop, and a piano usually has more white keys than black

Comment: Similarly I think the first one is close but not quite right. I'm not clear what the "smooth slide" is (your guess seems ok), but the initial climb is up a man's beard, The pyramid is of course the nose; the pink moon-shaped hole is the mouth, open enough to reveal the gigantic white plates (teeth). Between pyramid (nose) and hole (mouth) is the moustache, which is of course stiffer than the beard hair initially climbed.

Comment: It mentions MULTIPLE holes for the first one.. I doubt that it is a mouth.

Comment: @WeckarE., it's not very clear as in the text it says "...pinkish holes...inside that hole". So it seems more like a typo

Comment: @WeckarE. (specifically, "holes" is mentioned once, and "hole" twice; I had started by assuming the mouth was mostly closed with the lips stuck together in some places, leaving a few open holes behind, before I realized due to the two other places where "hole" is singular that the original mention of "holes" is likely a typo)